# Server doesn't alloc a thread for every new client (sockets)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I made a small program server client using sockets. I'll will explain what it needs to do and then the bug.

Application has a server witch wait's for clients. It supports max 6 clients at the same time. For each client server launch a thread in DETASH_STATE and then it come back and listen.

A client will submit the context of a file to the server. (i chose to send line by line)

The server will receive the content sent by a client and save it into a file, with a unique name like: __ft_"Any random string".txt

I hope all is clear till now.

The bug:
Well if i launch the client let say 20 times. On server side i don't have 20 files. Sometimes i have 10, sometimes 12,5,7(unpredictable). It writes in a single file the content sent by 3 or 4 or 5 clients ( here i need to have 3-4-5 files). I don't get where is the bug or what i  made wrong. If you need additional information please tell me.

This is the server code (a part of it):

```
/**********ASSING A PROTOCOL TO A SOCKET (BIND)************/

if(bind(sock_dest, (struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof (server))<0)
{
    printf("Bind failed\n");
    return 1;
}

/**********************************************************/

/*************** LISTEN FOR CONNECTIONS ********************/

listen(sock_dest,6);
printf("Waiting for connections\n");

/**********************************************************/


/****ACCEPT CONNECTION AND MAKE ATHREAD FOR EVERY CLIENT***/
c = sizeof ( struct sockaddr_in);
pthread_t thread_id;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

while( ( client_socket = accept( sock_dest, ( struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *) &c)) )
{
    printf("Connection accepted.\n");

    if(client_socket < 0)
    {
        printf("Accepting connection failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(pthread_create( &thread_id, &attr, connection_handler, (void*) &client_socket ) < 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create a thread for the new client.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    printf("Handler assigned\n");
}




return 0;
}


void *connection_handler (void *socket_dest)
{
char *dest_file_name;
char buffer[300];
int sock = *( int *) socket_dest;
char *exit_signal="EXIT";

if((dest_file_name=create_random_name())==NULL)
{
    printf("Generating a random name failed\n");
    return NULL;
}

int i=0;
while(1)
{
    while(i<299)
    {
        recv(sock,buffer+i,1,0);
        if(buffer[i]=='\n')
        {
            i=0;           // setting i to 0 because next time when we read a path(string) it need to be stored from 0 pozition in array.
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    if((strcmp(buffer,exit_signal))==0)
    {
        printf("Exit signal received.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if((write_line_in_file(buffer,dest_file_name))==1)
    {
        printf("Failed to write one of the lines in %s\n",dest_file_name);
    }


    printf("Linie primita:%s\n",buffer);

    bzero(buffer,256); // put all bytes to 0 from buffer
}

return 0;
}



char *create_random_name(void)
{
const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char *file_name;
int i=0;
int key;
struct stat stbuf;
time_t t;

while(1)
{

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    if((file_name = malloc(16 * sizeof ( char )) ) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to alloc memory space\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(file_name,"__ft_");
    for(i=5 ; i<11 ; i++)
    {
        key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset)-1);
        file_name[i]=charset[key];
    }
    strcat(file_name,".txt");
    file_name[15] = '\0';
    if(stat(file_name,&stbuf)==-1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
return file_name;
}

/************* RETURN 0 IF SUCCES AND 1 IF FAILS ***********/

int write_line_in_file(char *line,char *file_name)
{
FILE *file;
if((file=fopen(file_name, "a")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open %s.\n");
    return 1;
}
fprintf(file,"%s",line);
fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

And this is the client code (i don't think here is the problem):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/***************CHECKING THE ARGUMENT*************/
if (argc < 2)
{
   printf("Usage: %s hostname\n", argv[0]);
   return 1;
}
/*************************************************/

int sock_dest;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
char line[300];

/******************CREATE SOCKET*****************/

sock_dest = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock_dest == -1)
{
   printf("Couldn't create socket.\n");
   return 1;
}

struct hostent *server;
server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

if (server == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR, no such host\n");
    return 1;
}

/***** SETTING FIELDS OF SERVER SOCKADDR_IN STRUCTURE *****/

bzero((char *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
server_addr.sin_port = htons ( 31000 );

/**********************************************************/

/*********TRYING TO CONNECT TO THE SERVER******************/


if (connect(sock_dest,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR:(Can't connect to the server. Please check if it's online)\n");
    return 1;
}

/***********************************************************/

char path_read[200];
int read_len,n;
FILE *f_read;
char *exit_signal = "\nEXIT\0";
if((f_read=fopen("test.txt","r"))==NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open path.txt.\n");
    return 0;
}
while((fgets(path_read,200,f_read))!=NULL)
{
    path_read[strlen(path_read)+1]='\n';
    n = write(sock_dest,path_read,strlen(path_read));
    if(n<0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(path_read,200);
}

n=write(sock_dest,exit_signal,strlen(exit_signal));
fclose(f_read);
close(sock_dest);
printf("All lines in the file were sent to the server.\nExiting...\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking if your `create_random_name` function is generating the same file name more than 1 time.

Comment: is it possible to generate the same name and that is why it writes in the same file?

Comment: It is possible (The chances for that to happen are low, but they are there). Modify it so it will never return a name for a file that already exists

Comment: Thanks. I'm adding a call to stat function. If it returns -1 the name it's valid.

Comment: There is a tool called netcat which you can use to test simple TCP transfers. Use that tool as either server or client to find out whether your server side or your client side are at fault.

Comment: Take a look at the results: __ft_haljzo.txt     __ft_haljzoĹ.      __ft_haljzoŔ.       __ft_iejkmg.txt   __ft_jjenmw.txt. 2nd and 3rd results are not files. What  can i do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This is one bug:

```
(void*) &client_socket
```

Firstly, no need to cast to `void*`. Secondly, it looks like `client_socket` is a local variable, who's address you pass to the thread as context. In the starting thread, you then continue to overwrite its value with the next iteration.

Comment: Hello thanks for your time. What should i do with client_socket when  you say it is a local variable?

Comment: Firstly, it would really help if you provided a minimal example, as the site guidelines actually require. Then, how to properly pass context info to a thread should be explained or shown in any thread tutorial, so please go and read one! In order to fix it, you could either allocate the context info dynamically or pass the integer value as void pointer value.